# Basis for an ideal in Q[x]

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find a basis $\Bbb Q[x]$ of the ideal
$I=\{p_1(x) \in Q[x]| (x^2-x)p_1(x)+x^2p_2(x) − (x^2 + x)p_3(x) =0,  \}$ where $p_1(x),p_2(x) \in Q[x]$.

Dividing by $x$ and re-arranging yields
$(x-1)p_1(x)=-(x)p_2(x)+(x+1)p_3(x)$ where $-x,$ and $x+1$ are relatively prime and hence generated by the ideal ($1$). It seems wrong for me to just treat the monic generator of $p_1(x)$ to be ($1$) and then sub in values.

This is where I am stuck. Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is essentially right.

$I$ is an [ideal quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient):
$
I = (A : B) = \{p \in \mathbb Q[x] : pB \subset A\}
$,
where $B=(x^2-x)$ and $A=(x^2,x^2+x)=(x^2,x)=(x)$.

Since, $B \subset A$, we have $I = (A : B) = \mathbb Q[x]$.

Comment: why does $(A:B) = \Bbb Q[x]$